# Check variable run time Type in flutter with conditions like "123" is present as a String but is a int so how can i check this?

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling, conditional-statements, runtime-type

I have to check runtime Type of value for this I am using :-

for Example:-

String a = "abc";

int b = 123;

var c = "123";    //this is int value but because of this double quotes is represent as a String

a.runtimeType == String  //true

b.runtimeType == int  // true

c.runtimeType == String   //true

c.runtimeType == int   //false

a  =  "abc" // okay

b = 123 //okay

c = "123" //is issue

**now I have to call a api with only String body in this case** :-

**this c is called the API because is String but i know this is a int value which is present as a String, so I have to stop this.**

How can I check this??

when I am using try catch so my program is stopped because of FormatException error.

Note:-  I don't know the real value of C, may be its "123" or "65dev" or "strjf" this value is changed every time.

and if i am parsing this in int to this return an error in many case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you're passing it to API but if you wanna pass integer value from string quoted variable, you can parse/convert to integer like this.

**int.parse(c);**

either you can pass it directly or you can store in another variable and pass that variable.
Alternatively if you've int value and to have to pass it as a string, simply parse like this

integerValue.toString();
according to your code

**b.toString();**

**Edit**

```
  String a = '20';
  String b = 'a20';
  
  try{
  int check = int.parse(a);
 //call your api inside try then inside if
  if(check.runtimeType == int){
    print('parsed $check');
     }
  }
  catch(e){
    
    print('not parsed ');
    //handle your error
    throw(e);
  }
```

Comment: i don't know the real value may is "123" or "12dev" and when i am parsing this in int so its return an error i many  case. because this value is changed every time.

Comment: do you wanna say, value either be an integer or string? If so, you can make your variable dynamic on app side, if still not solved then it may be mistake in API response

Comment: i want to call APi only with String body, if int present as string so its called and i have to stop this, if int present as a String so its not able to call the API.

Comment: Okay I understand. I'm editing my answer you can do like that.

Comment: okay, thank you, I am waiting.

Comment: if you don't want to throw exception you can do other things

Answer (score 0):

Ok i understood that you want to pass **"123"** by checking and if it is **int** you are passing it , My question is what you will do if it is **"123fe"** you are going to pass as **string**? or you will pass **nothing**.

Comment: "nothing " in this case Api is not called,  i want to call Api only with String body,  like "abc" or "dev"

Comment: can you tell me which language are you using

Comment: look about **regex expressions** to validate if your string contains numbers or not definitely you'll solve problem using this

Comment: i am using dart language, and if am using try catch so exception in coming in many cases.

Answer (score 0):

This will definitely help you!

```
String name = "5Syed8Ibrahim";
final RegExp nameRegExp = RegExp(r'^[a-zA-Z ][a-zA-Z ]*[a-zA-Z ]$');
print(nameRegExp.hasMatch(name));


//output false


name = "syed ibrahim";
print(nameRegExp.hasMatch(name));


//output true
```

Just check the output and based on that boolean value invoke api call

**I hope it will done the work**